# Cannot find module 'expressValidator'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is a strange error when I try to use expressValidator module in nodejs.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'expressValidator'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\learning\nodejs_udemy\node_auth\app.js:5:
24)
```

Any mistake I made in my app.js?

```
var expressValidator = require('expressValidator');

// validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));
```

I follow the github usage guide but I still got an error.

Comment: And you have actually installed that?

Answer (score 2):

[npm modules can't have uppercase letters](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), the module is called `express-validator`, not `expressValidator`. As stated in express-validator's [documentation](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator), do:

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
```

make sure to

```
npm i --save express-validator
```

before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. On my case I did a pull request from git and didn't install all latest packages.

```
yarn install
```

OR

`npm install`